# android opengl slowdown after sprites are drawn

Tags: android, opengl-es

Sorry for the non-descriptive title to this post, but I just couldn't phrase it (please suggest a better title if you think of one).

A part of my current engine calls a quad to be rendered over and over for dynamic lights... and it seemed to be working fine, but for some weird reason after a few lights are created then destroyed the game remains as slow as it would be if they were still being drawn... I'm wondering if my drawSprite function is leaving something in memory...

Here is the function with a slimmed down version of the function that calls it:

```
    public void lightBlock(GL10 gl, int _x, int _y, float shade)
    {   

        if (map[_x][_y].Type()==1)
        {
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(_x*2,getFH(_x,_y)+.01f,_y*2);
        gl.glRotatef(90,1, 0, 0);
        gl.glScalef(2, 2, 0);
        gl.glColor4f(shade,shade,shade, 1f);
        drawSprite(gl,0);

        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(_x*2,getRH(_x,_y)-.01f,_y*2);
        gl.glRotatef(-90,1, 0, 0);
        gl.glScalef(2, 2, 0);
        gl.glColor4f(shade,shade,shade, 1f);
        //Draw the vertices
        drawSprite(gl,0);

        gl.glPopMatrix();
        }

    }

    public void drawSprite(GL10 gl, int tex)
    {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);      
        //defines the vertices we want to draw
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, SvertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, StexBuffer);

        //Draw the vertices
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,  6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,  SindexBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
```

If the lights are not in use, these functions are not called... but oddly enough once they have been called many times, the game runs as slow as it would be if they were all running at once... And it runs normally as soon as I comment out the "drawSprite()" calls...

The lights are called inside the "onDrawFrame" function.

Any help would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you aren't making too many of the objects?

I had a problem where it got progressively slower, turned out I wasn't clearing my "addToScene" list. This mean every frame I was adding annother set of all the entities in my game.

If you are doing that with sprites, you won't notice the slowdown if you comment out the thing that takes time - ie the drawing.